# Tratando de testear el tipo NotFoundResult falla devolviendo null (xUnit, ASP.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tengo un controlador con éste método

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Unidad> GetUnidad(int id) {
   var unidad = _context.Unidades.Find(id);
   if (unidad == null) {
       return NotFound();
   }
   return unidad;
}
```

Y una Unit Test que chequea que el valor devuelto sea del tipo NotFoundResult cuando solicito un id no existente en la base (para este unit test el controlador se crea con un context InMemory vacío):

```
// Propiedades de la clase
UnidadesController controller;
DbContextOptionsBuilder<PaoMazzaAPIContext> optionsBuilder;
PaoMazzaAPIContext dbContext;

// Constructor
public UnidadesControllerTests()
{
   optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PaoMazzaAPIContext>();
   optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("UnitTestInMemDb");
   dbContext = new PaoMazzaAPIContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
   controller = new UnidadesController(dbContext);
}

// Test
[Fact]
public void GetUnidad_Return404_WhenIDIsInvalid() {
    var result = controller.GetUnidad(0);
    Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(result.Value);
}
```

Sin embargo el test falla porque Value es null, cuando debería ser del tipo NotFoundResult. La salida del testeo es:

```
   Assert.IsType() Failure
Expected: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult
Actual:   (null)
```

Alguna sugerencia? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Listo, ya está en español, no me di cuenta.

Comment: como instancias `controller` y como le pasas el `_context` ?

Answer (score 0):

No observo en el codigo que nos muestras que este utilizando `moq`

[Unit test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Si revisas el articulo veras que deberias usar

```
[Fact]
public void GetUnidad_Return404_WhenIDIsInvalid() {

    var mockContext = new Mock<NombreDbContext>();
    mockContext.SetupGet(m => m.Unidades)
        .Returns(new DbSet<Unidad>());
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Unidades.Find(It.Any<int>()))
        .Returns(null);
        
    var controller = new HomeController(mockContext.Object);
    
    var result = controller.GetUnidad(0);
    
    Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(result);
}
```

Esto suponiendo que inyectas el `dbcontext` en el constructor del `controller`, asi aseguras que al realizar el `Find()` obtendras un null y po consiguiente el notfound en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, pero fijate que ahí actualicé la entrada. En el constructor de la Unit Test creo el context como una base en memoria vacía, con lo cual al llamar el método del controler pidiendo un elemento específico se devuelve NotFound(), que debería ser del tipo NotFoundResult, sin embargo falla diciéndome que el valor devuelto es simplemente null.